# magento: 2.4.3: Add Content - Products Carousel not show arrows and dots in page Home Page

Tags: product

I added Product Carousel it not show image, arrows and dots in page Home Page
[image]

[image]

Please! Help me!

Answer (score 0):

It's showed. I added > 6 products. It's work